Cannot pip install scikit-learn, pkgutil and ImpImporter
I just went to Python 3.12.3.  I cannot pip3 install scikit_learn==1.1.3.  I get the following error:
 File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2zt7oob5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2172, in <module>
      register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I have tried updating pip, I tried specifying a particular version of numpy first.  Can this work with Python 3.12, or what might be going on here?

So version 1.5.1 does work for me.  Does this just mean that I am using a version of scikit-learn that is too old for python 3.12?

pkgutil.ImpImporter was removed in Python 3.12. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError+%22module+pkgutil+has+no+attribute+ImpImporter%22

@omnes_flumina yes, exactly. That version is only compatible up to python 3.11

@FlyingTeller Thanks!  I have replaced == with >= in my requirements.txt file.  It is an inherited file I am working with

scikit-learn 1.1.3 supports only Python 3.8 - 3.11. Support for Python 3.12 came with scikit-learn 1.3.1 as can be seen in its wheel files. Any version of scikit-learn >= 1.3.1 is compatible with Python 3.12.
